# PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: image, yii2

I'm trying to display an image in the view page instead of displaying the image name. [image]

In my view.php I have included this code

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            //'business_id',
            'business_name',
            'address',
            //'description',
            'contact_number',
            'email_address:email',
            'area',
            'city',
            'pincode',
             [
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'format' => 'image',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->getImageUrl(); 
                },
            ],
           // 'longitude',
           // 'latitude',
            'serviceType',
            'business_open',
            'business_close',

            //'available_flag',
            'delivery_duration',
            //'del_flg',
            //'create_date',
           // 'update_date',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

And i have a function in my model like this

```
public function getImageUrl(){
        if(isset($this->image) && !empty($this->image)) { 
            return \yii\helpers\Url::to('../uploads/business/'.$this->image,['width' => 100,'height'=>60], true);
        }
    }
```

when clicking on the view button, im getting a warning as "strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" 
Im failing to find out any solution for this.. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** 
Try this..

```
function getImageUrl(){
     if(isset($this->image) && !empty($this->image)) { 
         return \yii\helpers\Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/uploads/business/'.$this->image, ['width' => 100,'height'=>60]);
}
```

and use above mothod like

```
[
      'attribute' => 'image',
      'format' => 'image',
      'value' => $model->getImageUrl(); 
  ],
```

Comment: Im getting the same warning.. no change

Comment: In `DetailView` no need to use `function()` in `value` property.